How to reference the entire Dataset inside of a query
So I'm building a search function to help me find any matches within a dataset in google sheets.
I'm currently using I'm trying to condense my current formula by referencing the entire dataset once as opposed to doing so 10 times
Here's my current code
=QUERY(Database!B5:M3981,"SELECT * where B contains '"&$B2&"' or C contains '"&$B2&"' or D contains '"&$B2&"' or E contains '"&$B2&"'  or F contains '"&$B2&"' or H contains '"&$B2&"'",0)

instead I would like to have it look something like this
=QUERY(Database!B5:M3981,"SELECT * where ____ contains '"&$B2&"'",0)

Having something to reference all the rows at the same time at the place of ____.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Use filter(), byrow() and search(), like this:
=let( 
  data, Database!B5:M, 
  filter(
    data, 
    byrow(data, lambda(row, 
      sum(iferror(search(B2, row))) 
    )) 
  ) 
)

See
let(),
filter(),
byrow(),
and
search().
